# If I bought one treasury bond for 100.0 ($1000), then its market price become 110.0, does my profit be $100?

Tags: bonds, treasury

If I bought one treasury bond for 100.0 ($1000), then its market price become 110.0, if I sold it, does my profit will be $100? and does all other bonds' profits (municipal, corporate, international..etc) calculated the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Profit is sales price - cost - expenses. So yes, if you bought something for $1000 and sold it for $1,100 your profit is $100, assuming no transaction fees.

It is irrelevant if you are buying and selling bonds, trading cards, or broomsticks.